# Send HTML code to Body of email application

Tags: c#, javascript, html-email

Is there a way I can use `mailto:` or JavaScript to send a string containing HTML code to the body of an email message so that the HTML will render? This just renders as text and doesn't actually display an image (same for a mailto: link):

```
window.open('email@email.com&Subject=Test&Body=<img src="MyImageURL" />');
```

In the real code, I'm using the full URL of the image, with the `http://www...`, and also, I confirmed that the email type is HTML and not plain text.

This is a project requirement, to allow someone to send a formatted message through their own email rather than us sending it server-side on their behalf through our SMTP server.

Comment: Also, the email application I've been testing in so far is Outlook.

Comment: Your outlook displays other HTML messages as HTML right?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?  Your description discusses only JS.  Are you allowing server side answers?

Comment: Omer, yes, if I copy/paste the image from the browser it displays fine.

Comment: P.Brian.Mackey, server side answers are fine, whatever works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there is no way to do this using javascript or mailto. if you wanna read all features to mailto protocol please check [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) page.