# Any way to populate email body with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, email, outlook

I'm familiar with the limits and uses of the mailto link. It's pretty handy, but of course, my client would like to manipulate the body more than plain text will accommodate.

I've seen questions like this one: [Send HTML code to Body of email application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412837/send-html-code-to-body-of-email-application)

But I want to expand on it.  I can restrict my users to iPad and Outlook 2016+.  So I wanted to know if there is a way to directly interact with apple mail and Outlook from a web app to generate a "pretty" email. I can detect if user is on iPad or not and run disparate code if needed for the two platforms.

I can even entertain throwing a server in the middle, but it's important that email ultimately opens on the client for additional personalization.

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: One Idea would be offering the user an `.eml` file as download and open it in compose mode. (like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916318/open-eml-files-in-compose-mode-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have that same idea but not sure how to do it and the link doesn't provide much info.

Comment: Something like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/8qef7qoz/ . (The bad thing is, it does not work that well. It just downloads a file and the user has to open it to write a mail. so not that ideal.)

Comment: That's a great start. Just need to get the path or something after it's downloaded and open it for them (especially important on iPad).

Comment: Several email clients like Gmail will strip the JavaScript. I don't have a comprehensive list.